# Join Tables Within Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_LIFE_CYCLE_CUST_DETAIL_PARM")
@Data
public class ActionCriteriaParameter extends BaseEntity {

    public static final String CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID = "custDetailInstanceId";
     .
     .
     .
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID)
     private CustomerDetailParameter custDetailInstanceId;
    .
    .
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_LIFE_CYCLE_CUST_DETAIL_PARM")
@Data
public class CustomerDetailParameter extends BaseEntity {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

their super class is

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "INSTANCE_ID")
    private Timestamp instanceId;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

To query these tables I have a Specification

```
import static com.garanti.proactiveretention.data.ActionCriteriaParameter.*;

public class ActionCriteriaParameterSpecification  implements Specification<ActionCriteriaParameter> {

    private Long custDetailInstanceId;
    .
    .
    .

    public ActionCriteriaParameterSpecification(Long custDetailInstanceId, ...) {
        this.custDetailInstanceId= custDetailInstanceId;
    .
    .
    .

    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ActionCriteriaParameter> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        Join<ActionCriteriaParameter, CustomerDetailParameter> join = root.join(CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this.custDetailInstanceId!= null) predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID), custDetailInstanceId));
    .
    .
    .

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }


}
```

When I try to query with CRUDRepository

```
actionCriteriaParameterRepository.findAll(new ActionCriteriaParameterSpecification(customerDetailParameter, status, actionType, min, max, explanationText)).stream().map(this::convertToActionCriteriaDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with
>   the the given name [custDetailInstanceId] on this ManagedType
>   [com.garanti.proactiveretention.data.BaseEntity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use entity fields names inside `Specification` instead of database columns names.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_LIFE_CYCLE_CUST_DETAIL_PARM")
@Data
public class ActionCriteriaParameter extends BaseEntity {

    public static final String CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID = "CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID"; // database column name
     .
     .
     .
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID) // database column name
     private CustomerDetailParameter customerDetailParameter; // entity field name
    .
    .
}
```

Specification code

```
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ActionCriteriaParameter> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        Join<ActionCriteriaParameter, CustomerDetailParameter> join = root.join("customerDetailParameter");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this.custDetailInstanceId!= null) 
           predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("instanceId"), custDetailInstanceId)); 
           // where "instanceId" - CustomerDetailParameter id field name
           // ???? why BaseEntity field instanceId is Timestamp, but custDetailInstanceId has Long type
    .
    .
    .

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

Comment: I got the error on line root.join(CUST_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID);

Comment: Now I got same error with replaced value
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [customerDetailParameter]

Comment: You have to replace database columns names to entity fields names elsewhere in criteria related code.

Comment: Like private CustomerDetailParameter customerDetailParameter; to private CustomerDetailParameter custDetailInstanceId ?;

Comment: Edited the question. Same error  Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [custDetailInstanceId] on this ManagedType [com.garanti.proactiveretention.data.BaseEntity]

Would you mind if I ask you to edit your answer too ?

Comment: Thank you. I use Long because Timestamp value comes from controller's method path parameter so it can't be converted to String.

Comment: You have to convert it properly before using in specification